Amazon Connect and Lex for Phone IVR
I am having trouble gathering information from a Lex bot in Amazon Connect during a Get Customer Input block. I have a block that asks the caller for their first and last name, and this works perfectly, storing the values as session attributes. However, I am encountering an issue with capturing the customer’s account number.
In Lex, I have an intent called "capture account number" with an account number slot type, and it works fine on the Lex console.
In Amazon Connect, when I try to use this intent, it asks the caller to provide their account number (as set from the Get Input text). However, as soon as the caller begins to speak, the block routes to the error path, and I am not sure why this happens. There are no bot timeouts set, and the Lex bot works fine in other blocks of the flow.
I know the setup should work because it functions correctly in the Lex console, but for some reason, it fails in Connect. I need assistance in identifying and fixing the issue.

The Intnet and Slot type are below also:



